# Finding a file and ignoring the permission denied

Tags: grep

I really need to find a file, and not only on my home directory

so I search from / but this gives a lot of "Permission denied" messages so I try

```
find / -type f -name a_file | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

But I still get the "Permission denied" and I can't find the file

Why is grep not filtering out the messages?